# The weight of a word

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Can someone please direct me to sources, systems, or a way of measuring the weight or substance a word holds. Its synonymous value. Also without considering sentencing, just general. 
Although the sub categories of poetic, novel, speech, humor, and or literature ect. apply
Like if a word has multiple origins and uses does it hold more value? Or does context overrule value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In everyday situations, where the practical considerations of information exchange tend to be supreme, when a word has multiple meanings it is context that usually makes one of them come to the fore.

In literary situations, where ambiguity and ironic use of language are not regarded as impediments to communication, when a word has multiple meanings it is context that may be the primary factor in determining the literal meaning, but secondary and tertiary meanings can still have some bearing and form "subtext".

Of course, there is a gray area in conversation, since not all speech in non-literary contexts is of a purely practical nature, and people may choose their words carefully, taking connotation, not merely denotation, into account.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the *synonymous weight* (my suggestion for the name) of a word, then I assume the units will be plain numbers (i.e. the number of synonyms the word has).  You can define it as such if you are writing about it.

As for a source - it depends on your familiarity with technology.  If you are good with computers, you could for example write some Excel  Visual Basic that will read the text of a thesaurus such as https://www.thesaurus.com/ - This would allow you to create your own database. You might also wish to create an interactive [word-cloud](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Word_clouds)  of synonyms.  If this doesn't already exist I'm sure it would be **very** popular as an online resource.

As for pre-existing sources and an pre-existing name for this, I suggest you consult https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ - If anyone knows, they will.

---

**Notes**

1. Other names for "word-cloud" are "tag cloud" and "weighted list". Here is an example although not quite what you want - you can see the principle though.
   [image]
2. Searching online for anything to do with synonyms can be frustrating to say the least. If you search for a "list of synonyms", you are more likely to get  synonyms of the word "list"!